# Car overtaking — what function can be used to model this?

Tags: calculus, robotics

I want to compute the difference in time dependent on the maximum distance that is reached when a car overtakes another.

Assuming the use of two variables (time and horizontal distance) what function would be best in solving this problem. I imagine that the overtaking has a hemi-elliptical phase, we approach the car in front (horizontal distance = 0 than we start overtaking, horizontal distance increases to a maximum when cars are parallel to each other and than we return symmetrically until horizontal distance becomes 0).

If we neglect any physical phenomena, what function can be used to describe this pattern?

We have to assume that the movement of cars are uniform and continuous so the function can be derived (for example we can't imagine a trapezoid shape).

I think that this can be modeled with derivative of sin hyperbolic function. What do you think?

Comment: Presumably you want a stage when the car is moving straight in the adjacent lane. Does it make sense to split the problem in two identical parts, each one crossing a lane?

Comment: So you want a function that takes you from $x=0$ to $x=1$ smoothly in time $t$. Will a function like $x(t)=(t - 2 a +\sqrt{t^2 + 4 a^2})/(2 t)$ suffice? ($a$ is a parameter.)

Comment: Can you explain a bit how did u solve this ?

Comment: I didn't solve anything. I created a function $vt=-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}$ consisting of two poles, and then I inverted.

Comment: There are PhD theses on nonlinear trajectory generation. You can combine splines and differential geometry. How deep do you want to go?

Comment: I thought that this could be a good aplication for univariable calcuclus aproximation. I took recently a lecture about this. so I don t want to go very deep. I want to keep it as simple as possible and as didactic as posible.

Comment: You're thinking of the trajectory. What if you think of the driver? Imagine you have a remote controlled car. How would you steer it? Given (admissible) "steering functions", one obtains a feasible trajectory. If one starts with the trajectory, there may be no steering functions that lead to it. In other words, the desired trajectory may be infeasible. I would start with a toy model of an automobile and then think of how to steer it. Take a look at Richard Murray's [chapter](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/AM08/pdf/obc-trajgen_03Jan10.pdf) [PDF]. Perhaps too advanced, but interesting.

Comment: What I meant was the following. Pick the simplest toy model of a car. Pick the simplest steering function, say, something [bang-bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang–bang_control). Try to determine the resulting trajectory. Find the maximal horizontal distance (which depends on the toy model of the car). This is probably much more complicated than what you desire. To keep it simple, try the [tangent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html). No need for hyperbolic functions.